# Iterating over large amounts of data in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I am looking for an efficient way to iterate over the full data of a influxDB table with ~250 million entries.
I am currently paginating the data by using the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses, however this takes takes a lot of time for higher offsets.

```
SELECT * FROM diff ORDER BY time LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 0
```

takes 21 seconds, whereas

```
SELECT * FROM diff ORDER BY time LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 40000000
```

takes 221 seconds.

I am using the Python influxdb wrapper to send the requests.

Is there a way to optimize this or stream the whole table?

---

UPDATE : Rembering the timestamp of the last received data, and then using a WHERE time >= last_timestamp on the next query, reduces the query time for higher offsets drastically (query time is always ~25 secs). This is rather cumbersome however, because if two data points share the same timestamp, some results might be present on two pages of data, which has to be detected somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Continuous Queries or Kapacitor. Can you elaborate on your use-case, what you're doing with the stream of data?

Comment: I am using past data that represents updates on financial order books to reconstruct the history for simulation purposes. The influxDB querying had become the bottleneck for the application, especially for higher offsets. However, I found a workaround where using a WHERE clause instead of an OFFSET, (and remembering the last received timestamp for each page of data), which reduces the time to query drastically. Not sure why the OFFSET takes so much time...